# Sorting image files using header information

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, text-formatting

I have multiple image files inside a directory having the same extension (.mrc). In the terminal, if I do, header , it gives following output:

```
 RO image file on unit   1 : FoilHole_17224697_Data_18256098_18256099_20150819_2015.mrc     Size=      65537 K

         This file has invalid axis indices, adjusting them to 1,2,3

 Number of columns, rows, sections .....    4096    4096       1
 Map mode ..............................    2   (32-bit real)              
 Start cols, rows, sects, grid x,y,z ...    0     0     0    4096   4096      1
 Pixel spacing (Angstroms)..............   1.000      1.000      1.000    
 Cell angles ...........................    0.000    0.000    0.000
 Fast, medium, slow axes ...............    X    X    X
 Origin on x,y,z .......................    0.000       0.000       0.000    
 Minimum density .......................   2056.0                               
 Maximum density .......................   4462.0                               
 Mean density ..........................   3213.5                               
 tilt angles (original,current) ........   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 Space group,# extra bytes,idtype,lens .        0        0        0        0

     1 Titles :
EMAN 9/18/2015 15:41
```

I am looking for a script where I could specify a range for the "Mean density" value and selected files who contain their "Mean density" value in that range get copied to a new directory.

NB: Header is a program from IMOD image processing package. For more information on the function 'header' plaese visit: http://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/doc/program_listing.html#TOP

Comment: You "do" header? Can you elaborate on that? :-)

Comment: I guess that header is a smart program that is presenting the .mrc header in an human readable format, at least my answer below is based on this assumption :)

Comment: @herbert - and that's a very fair assumption.  I thought I'd get the OP to edit so that someone doesn't come along in a couple of hours and close the question as "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what `header` is. Is it a script? A program from the repositories? How can we install it so we can test its output and try to help you?

Comment: Hi everyone, I'm sorry I didn't explain what 'header' is. Its a program from IMOD image processing suite. The description can be found at-http://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/doc/program_listing.html#TOP

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have dedicated tools to list information about your .mrc file, I would suggest you to use some scripting language that have pack/unpack feature and that can handle floating value, like perl for instance.
If the output that you just printed is the output of a command then you can 
do grep on a for loop:

```
$!/bin/sh

treshold=42.0
for file in *.mrc
do
mean_density=$(header $file | grep "Mean density" | awk '{print $2}')
if [ $(echo "$mean_density>$treshold" | bc) -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "$i match!"
fi
done
```

Edit,

assuming that "header" command will print the header of your .mrc file in a format that you are quoting in your question. If you have no such program then perl unpack function is definitely what you need.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to run your script. Maybe I am missing something. Yes, 'header' is a program from image processing package IMOD. Link: http://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/doc/program_listing.html#TOP. About using perl - I don't have much knowledge about programming, so will wait for your answer....

Answer (score 0):

If the range you're looking for is something like 3,000 - 3,999, the command

```
grep -L -E "^Mean density \.+ 3\d\d\d(\.\d+)?$" *.mrc
```

should print the list of files with the mean density you're looking for.  More complicated regexes are possible.  Or, if you need to run `header` to get the human-readable form, you'd pipe the output to `egrep` and test the return value `for f in *.mrc`.